# Iterate through files, divide two variables and extract the results, including identifier column using name of the original file

Tags: r, loops

I am stuck with a for loop and would need some help please. I use R for certain statistics, but what I need to do now exceeds what I know and can learn without some help. I really appreciate your time.

I edited the question and hope I made it clearer now.

I need to loop over every file in a folder and perform following actions on each file:

- Load the data
- Identify rows that correspond to variable A (in my case, the coverage of the chromosome, ChromosomeCoverage, numerical)
- Identify rows that correspond to variable B (in my case, the coverage
  of the phage, PhageCoverage, numerical)
- Estimate the mode value (ChromosomeModeEstimate) of variable A (ChromosomeCoverage) which I will use in the next step
- Calculate variable C (normalized values of B, C <- PhageCoverage/ChromosomeModeEstimate)
- Save C into separate document
- Save file name also in this separate document, to know for which file the normalized values are created

Each file in my folder has same dimensions; 4 columns and 45808 rows. The first and the last 5000 rows contain values that should be allocated to ChromosomeCoverage and in between are the values for the PhageCoverage. Files look like this (the 3. and 4. column need to be summed up first before proceeding to next steps, see below):

```
position    ref_base    unique_top_cov  unique_bot_cov
661401  T   26  23
661402  T   26  23
661403  C   26  23
661404  T   26  23
661405  C   26  23
661406  C   25  23
661407  G   25  23
661408  T   25  23
661409  G   23  25
```

These are the raw data and I first need to sum unique_top_cov and unique_bot_cov, to obtain the total coverage values, and then perform the other steps.
My script so far goes like this:

```
library(modeest) #estimate mode
data_files <- Sys.glob("*reg1.tab") # list all tab files that need to be iterated through 
results = list() # In my latest tries I attempted to put the normalized values in a list or vector but couldn’t make it to work. I also tried making an empty dataframe, but similarly unsuccessful (results <- data.frame(ID=character(), normalized=numeric()))

for (i in data_files) {

Data <- read.table(i, header = TRUE, sep = "\t") #read the files
ChromosomeCoverage <- c(Data$unique_bot_cov[1:5000]+Data$unique_top_cov[1:5000],
Data$unique_bot_cov[(length(Data$unique_bot_cov)5000):length(Data$unique_bot_cov)]+
Data$unique_top_cov[(length(Data$unique_top_cov)-5000):length(Data$unique_top_cov)]) #identify chromosome coverage

PhageCoverage <- Data$unique_bot_cov[5001:(length(Data$unique_top_cov)-5001)]+Data$unique_top_cov[5001:(length(Data$unique_top_cov)-5001)] #identify phage coverage

ChromosomeModeEstimate <- mlv(ChromosomeCoverage[ChromosomeCoverage>0]) #consider only values above 0

norm <- PhageCoverage/ChromosomeModeEstimate # here I made my normalized variable and this is where my problems begin. I tried multiple lines of code to somehow try and extract the filenames and normalized values into another dataframe, here only some examples:

filename = data_files[i]
normalized = norm[i]
append(results, c(filename, normalized)) # my results were empty 

#When instead of the list, I made my output as an empty dataframe, I tried for example
#results$ID[i] <- paste(unique(data_files))  
results$ID[i] <- data_files[i]
results$normalised[i] <- norm
}
```

I kind of don’t know what I am doing here. I don’t know how to append data to the output that needs to grow with each loop. I found how to add a separate column within each of the files that contains file name as identifier for each row, but then again I don’t know how to extract only the part of the column which covers phage region (so first and last 5000 rows removed).

Many thanks for looking at this, I appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple, I am assuming that `filename` contains a string and that `normalized` contains a number:

```
results <- list()
filename <- "myfile.tab"
normalized <- 1
```

Doing what you are doing:

```
append(results, c(filename, normalized))
```

gives me two issues. Combining a character and numeric into a vector coerces the numeric to character:

```
> c(filename, normalized)
[1] "myfile.tab" "1"
```

Not too hard to deal with but you need to be aware of this.
The other issues is that `append` does not reassign the value to your object. Your code only results in printing the appended object to the console:

```
> x <- c(1, 2)
> append(x, 3)
[1] 1 2 3
> x
[1] 1 2
```

So you have to do instead:

```
> x <- c(1, 2)
> x <- append(x, 3)
> x
[1] 1 2 3
```

In your case:

```
results <- list()
filename <- "myfile.tab"
normalized <- 1

results <- append(results, c(filename, normalized))
```

Comment: Thank you Paul, yes, this:
`results <- append(results, c(filename, normalized))` did help, but I had other issues in my code before this line that made the results unusable. I will post the solution as the answer

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me in the end:

```
setwd("")
library(modeest)

#choose all files with pattern ending with reg1.tab
filename <- Sys.glob("*reg1.tab") 
#create an empty vector 
results <- c() 

for (i in 1:length(filename)){
  # Load the data
  Data <- read.table(filename[i], header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
  # Identify ChromosomeCoverage
  ChromosomeCoverage<-c(Data$unique_bot_cov[1:5000]+Data$unique_top_cov[1:5000],
                        Data$unique_bot_cov[(length(Data$unique_bot_cov)-5000):length(Data$unique_bot_cov)]+
                        Data$unique_top_cov[(length(Data$unique_top_cov)-5000):length(Data$unique_top_cov)])
  # Identify PhageCoverage
  PhageCoverage<-Data$unique_bot_cov[5001:(length(Data$unique_top_cov)-5001)]+Data$unique_top_cov[5001:(length(Data$unique_top_cov)-5001)]
  # Estimate the mode value and consider only the values higher then 0
  ChromosomeModeEstimate<-mlv(ChromosomeCoverage[ChromosomeCoverage>0])
  # Save normalized values into a numeric vector num[1:35807]
  normalized <- PhageCoverage/ChromosomeModeEstimate
  #bind the rows into results object. For each file loaded I obtained 1 row with 35807 columns. Filename [i] incorporated the name of each file into the first column 
  results <- rbind(results, c(filename[i], normalized)) 
}

write.csv(results,"X:/XX/XX//Results.csv")
```

The saved file looks like this for the first 5 rows:

```
    V1  V2  V3  V4
1   C1758_reg1.tab  4.568627451 4.529411765 4.509803922
2   C1759_reg1.tab  2.381818182 2.363636364 2.345454545
3   C1763_reg1.tab  1.55    1.55    1.55
4   C1764_reg1.tab  4.476190476 4.523809524 4.476190476
5   C1765_reg1.tab  2.567375887 2.581560284 2.567375887
```